# How to export layer without losing formatting in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, export, formatting

I'm having trouble exporting a layer to send to a colleague whilst maintaining the formatting. This is mainly an issue as the layer is made up of many polygons, which are all overlapping to create this coloured map. I need to maintain the order of this 'layering'.... The first picture below is what the layer looks like on my computer, the second picture is how it comes out after I export it. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can also save your data in a geopackage. In a geopackage, you can also save the symbology of the layers.
So at the end, your colleagues just need to open the layer, and the default symbology is also loaded.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I worked out how to save the style, under the same name as the shapefile, and that has worked for now.